# Select only current row

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a shipment system, where Admins update shipment info when shipment location changes. In the admin dashboard I am trying to show the shipment details with a while loop but I get duplicate rows because anytime shipment location changes I save it. What I want is to only show the current location in `zt_location`.

```
try { $stmt = $db->prepare("
SELECT d.destination_id
     , d.recipient_name
     , s.shipment_id
     , s.tracking_number
     , s.time_added
     , o.origin_id
     , o.sender_name
     , l.location_id
     , l.location_facility
     , x.shipment_status_id
     , x.shipment_status
     , x.shipment_id
  FROM zt_shipment s
  JOIN zt_destination d
    ON d.shipment_id = s.shipment_id 
  JOIN zt_origin o
    ON o.shipment_id = s.shipment_id 
  JOIN zt_location l
    ON l.shipment_id = s.shipment_id 
  JOIN zt_shipment_status x
    ON x.shipment_id = s.shipment_id 
 ORDER 
    BY s.shipment_id DESC 
 LIMIT 0,6

");
                                                      
$stmt->execute();
}
                                                       
catch(PDOException $e) {
 echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
}

<?php
 while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) )
{ ?>

//HTML content

<?php }?>
```

Comment: Your application code has no way of distinguishing between the two shipment_ids. They're identical, but the code doesn't know that.

Comment: @Strawberry... Yes I know that but the issue is how to go about it.

Comment: Well, one idea is to not select the same information twice. Another is to give each instance of that column a column alias. But that's not what your question is about.

Comment: @Strawberry I dont want to select the same l.location_facility twice.. rather I want to select only the current location

Comment: Yep, that's separate from the point I was making, hence why it's a comment and not an answer. For further help with your actual problem, see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - but note that variations on this problem are amongst the most frequently asked under the MySQL tag.

Comment: thanks.. let me check it out.... is there a way I can compare two times and select only the current one?

Comment: Of  course. See above.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the GROUP BY statement to distinct down the rows.

```
SELECT 
 s.shipment_id,
 s.tracking_number,
 s.time_added,
 l.location_id,
 l.location_facility
FROM zt_shipment s
JOIN zt_destination d
  ON d.shipment_id = s.shipment_id 
JOIN zt_origin o
  ON o.shipment_id = s.shipment_id 
JOIN zt_location l
  ON l.shipment_id = s.shipment_id 
JOIN zt_shipment_status x
  ON x.shipment_id = s.shipment_id 
GROUP BY 
  s.shipment_id,
  s.tracking_number,
  s.time_added,
  l.location_id,
  l.location_facility
ORDER BY s.shipment_id DESC 
LIMIT 0,6
```

If you're wanting to show only the last 6 shipments created on your dashboard then you have the right query. Without some kind of filtering however this query will become cumbersome over time. Advise you to add a `WHERE date >= date_add(now(), interval -30 days)` or something of the like.

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate. As it happens, you're right, a GROUP BY clause *is* what's wanted here, but in conjunction with an aggregating function, and either as a subquery, or as CTE.

Comment: Agree to an extent. Best practice aside, a GROUP BY will solve OP's issue as I understand it or at least point them in the right direction.